# Compose the function $f$ $n$-times recurrently

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

The function $f$ is defined as $f(x) = 3x+2$.
If I were to compose the function $f$ $n$-times recurrently I would start doing it $n = 1$ times, $n = 2$ times etc., until I can find a pattern between the result and $n$.

So far I have:

- $n=1$: $(f∘f) = f(3x+2) = 3(3x+2)+2 = 9x+8$
- $n=2$: $f(f∘f) = f(9x+8) = 3(9x+8)+2 = 27x+26$
- $n=3$: $f(f∘f∘f) = f(27x+26) = 3(27x+26)+2 = 81x+80$

Do I need to find some sort of correlation between the result in square brackets and n to solve this particular problem?
Any help will be appreciated and this is my first post so I apologize if I haven't done it right :)

Comment: I'm no mind reader, but I've solved a few exercises in my time, and seen many more, and I think that yes, that is what they want you to do. Figure out a pattern to the two numbers in the square brackets, and describe it (with a formula or something similar). They want an answer that would, in principle, allow them to find the result for $n = 1000$ with a single calculation.

Comment: This is just a normal recurrence $a_{n+1}=3a_n+2$. Solve it by the recursion generals formulas method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rewrite your work, you get
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=3^1x+3^0\cdot2\\
f\circ f(x)&=3^2x+3^1\cdot 2+3^0\cdot2\\
f\circ f\circ f(x)&=3^3x+3^2\cdot 2+3^1\cdot 2+3^0\cdot 2\\
f\circ f\circ f\circ f(x)&=3^4x+3^3\cdot 2+3^2\cdot 2+3^1\cdot2+3^0\cdot 2
\end{align*}
Are you starting to see the pattern now?

Now, I expanded the constants to look at one way of seeing the pattern, but if you know geometric sums or are familiar with the powers of $3$, you might notice that the constants you get are nearly powers of $3$.  In fact, we can rewrite the entire expression as
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=3^1x+(3^1-1)\\
f\circ f(x)&=3^2x+(3^2-1)\\
f\circ f\circ f(x)&=3^3x+(3^3-1)\\
f\circ f\circ f\circ f(x)&=3^4x+(3^4-1)
\end{align*}
Here, the pattern may be even easier to discover.  Now, one could have jumped to this answer by just looking at your original work, but it's sometimes nice to see how to derive these types of formulas if you don't spot the answer right away.

Comment: That constant term looks a lot more complicated than it has to be. You say it shouldn't be simplified? I say simplify all the way.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, it is.

Comment: This has clarified everything for me so thanks a lot. This is my first time working with functions so needed reassuring I was on the right path. The pattern is much easier to spot in your example, in fact you don't even need to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, what is a problem?

It is almost for sure $$f^{(n)}(x) = 3^nx+3^n-1$$

Induction step:

\begin{eqnarray}f^{(n+1)}(x) &=& f(3^nx+3^n-1) \\&=& 3(3^nx+3^n-1) +2 \\&=& 3^{n+1}x+3^{n+1}-1 \end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

It is evident from your results so far that $$f^n(x) = 3^n x +(3^n-1).$$

You may prove this by Mathematical Induction.

It is true for $n=1$.

If it is true for $k$, then show that it is also true for $k+1.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,f_n=f^{(n)}(x)\,$ with $\,f_1=3x+2\,$, then $f_{n+1} = f\left(f_{n}\right) = 3 f_n + 2\,$. The latter can be written as  $\,f_{n+1}+1=3(f_n+1)\,$, so $\,f_n+1\,$ is a GP with common ratio $\,3\,$, thus $f_n + 1 = 3^{n-1}(f_1+1)$.